# How to use remote python modules

Tags: python-3.x, python-import, python-module

How I can use some 'extra' python module which is not located localy but on a remote server? Somthing like using maven dependencies with Java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be better off to install those modules locally.

Can you create packages of those modules (either using pip or something similar) then you can distribute them to your local box.

Of what I know, there is nothing similar.